# Emulate realistic liquid inside a bottle for animation

Tags: fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I am working on perfume bottle design. I am trying to create perfume in the bottle. When bottle is rotated, perfume stays static. What's the way to rotate perfume when bottle is rotated, or even placed slipping on floor. Like how a realistic bubble appears when bottle is sleeping on floor. It would be great help if the blender community share some light. Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far? Fluid simulations, dynamic paint, volumetric material? Also, please add an example of your desired result.